# Scalar potential in origo

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Find a scalar potential φ for the vector field F such that $\varphi(0,0)=5$ when

$$\mathbf{F}(x,y) = {3\cdot x\cdot \left(2\cdot y+1\right)}\mathbf{i}+{3\cdot x^2}\mathbf{j}$$

First we need to check that vector field is conservative so

$$\frac{\delta F_1}{\delta y}=\frac{\delta F_2}{\delta x}$$

$$6x=6x\to \frac{\delta F_1}{\delta y}-\frac{\delta F_2}{\delta x} = 0$$

then I want to find the  a scalar potential $\varphi$ for the vector field $\mathbf F$ such that $\varphi(0,0)=5$.

So

$$f_x ={3\cdot x\cdot \left(2\cdot y+1\right)} \to f= 3\cdot x^2 \cdot y^2+\frac{3\cdot x^2}{2}+g(y) $$

then

$$f_y=3\cdot x^2+g'(y)=3\cdot x^2\to g(y)=k$$

and $$f(x,y)= 3\cdot x^2 \cdot y^2+\frac{3\cdot x^2}{2}+k$$

and $\varphi$ for the vector field $\mathbf F$ such that $\varphi(0,0)=5$.

$$3\cdot 0^2 \cdot 0^2+\frac{3\cdot 0^2}{2}+k=5 \to k=5$$ but the $k=5$ is wrong answer. I have done some stupid mistake but I can't see where.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$f_x ={3\cdot x\cdot \left(2\cdot y+1\right)} \implies f= 3\cdot x^2 \cdot y+\frac{3\cdot x^2}{2}+g(y)$$

$$f_y=3\cdot x^2+g'(y)=3\cdot x^2\implies g(y)=k$$

and therefore

$$f(x,y)= 3\cdot x^2 \cdot y+\frac{3\cdot x^2}{2}+k$$

but in any case $k=5$ for the given condition.

Comment: @vvv We have $g(y)=k$ and $k=5$ in any case.